# Create a table with alphabetical sorting and search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wants to create a table (with alphabetical filter and search) like [this(example)](http://www.asimaindia.in/Member_Directory/). In which by clicking on any alphabet table shows name that started with only that alphabet. And also have a search option.

I have searched a lot on google but couldnt find table like that. Any one have any idea how i can get that table.

Comment: http://www.listjs.com/examples/table read the documentation to know how to do it

Comment: @Nuno Arruda Thanks for the link BUT it doesnt have the alphabet filter which i have mentioned in my question. For more detail please check out the example which i have shown In which A to Z alphabet filter is availble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution of my problem through the link provided below.

[SOLUTION IS HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758397/alphabetical-filter-in-table-not-working)

> Note : In this solution only alphabetical filter is available, search feature is not there. Search feature was not that important to me, so I am fine with only alphabet filter.

Answer (score 0):

On both letter click and search events, you should run a JS filter function on your data set and display only the relevant data.

A naive example of a filter function:

```
function filterByProperty(data, prop, searchString) {
    return data.filter(function(singleObject) {
        return singleObject[prop].indexOf(searchString) === 0;
    });
 }

 var dataSet = [
     {
         name: "Amanda",
         company: "Google"
     }, 
     {
         name: "Johnny",
         company: "Facebook"
     },
     { 
         name: "Max",
         company: "Go Daddy"
     }
 ];

 // Will return a collection containing the first and third objects in dataSet.
 var filteredData = filterByProperty(dataSet, "company", "G");
```

Answer (score 0):

It used a plugin called: DataTable, you can follow the guide here to make your own alphabet search.

https://www.datatables.net/blog/2014-08-26

No enough reputation to comment, so...

Answer (score 0):

From Chrome Developers(`Press F12 -> click on Network tab & reload the page`) tool

I see `dynamic-table.js`(not sure if this is library or custom file ) &

`jquery.dataTables.js`is used. So you can take a look into these library

[image: VIEW FROM CHROME DEVELOPERS TOOL]