# Alphabetical filter in table not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a table with alphabet filter in PHP. It was working fine without any issue. BUT i was developing it for wordpress project, So after successfully development in PHP I tried to imliment it in wordpress using `$wpdb`.

The problem I am facing now is that to filter we need to click any alphabet (suppose A) And after clicking All enteries that started from 'A' should return as output. But instead of returning Only 'A' entries Its returning whole table. In short filter is not working.

I am using this code in template file in wordpress.

```
global $wpdb;
?><div class="wrap"><div class="main-top"><div class="main"><h1><div    class="titlepage"><?php the_title();?></div></h1><?php
?><form action="memberspage.php" method="POST" name='search'  onclick="submit">
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=A">A</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=B">B</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=C">C</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=D">D</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=E">E</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=F">F</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=G">G</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=H">H</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=I">I</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=J">J</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=K">K</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=L">L</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=M">M</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=N">N</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=O">O</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=P">P</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=Q">Q</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=R">R</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=S">S</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=T">T</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=U">U</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=V">V</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=W">W</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=X">X</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=Y">Y</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911?letter=Z">Z</a> |
<a href="?page_id=911">View All</a> 
</form><?php
if(isset($_GET['letter']))
{
  $char=$_GET['letter'];

  if($char)
{
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM teacher_directory where Name LIKE     '$char%'", ARRAY_A  );
$count = $sql->num_rows;
if($count >= 1)
{
    echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>S. No.</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Designation</th>";
    echo "<th>Department</th>";
    echo "<th>Tele/Mob.No.</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($sql as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['S. No.'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Designation'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Tele/Mob.No.'] . "</td>";               
    echo "</tr>";
 }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>"; 
}}
}
```

> UPDATE   -: Since I got my answer, I am showing my final complete code(in working condition) for future viewers

If anyone is facing issue regarding Alphabetical filtered table then below code may solve your problem. It can be use in template file.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Table
*/
get_header();
?><div class="banner-box"><?php
global $wpdb;
?><div class="wrap"><div class="main-top"><div class="main"><h1><div  class="titlepage"><?php the_title();?></div></h1><div class="contcolor"><?php
?><form action="teacher.php" method="POST" name='search' onclick="submit"><a  href="?page_id=916&letter=A">A</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=B">B</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=C">C</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=D">D</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=E">E</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=F">F</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=G">G</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=H">H</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=I">I</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=J">J</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=K">K</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=L">L</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=M">M</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=N">N</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=O">O</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=P">P</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=Q">Q</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=R">R</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=S">S</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=T">T</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=U">U</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=V">V</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=W">W</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=X">X</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=Y">Y</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916&letter=Z">Z</a> |
<a href="?page_id=916">View All</a> 
</form><?php
if(isset($_GET['letter']))
{
  $char=$_GET['letter'];
  if($char)
{
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM teacher_directory where Name     LIKE '$char%'", ARRAY_A  );
$count = $results->num_rows;
?><div class="contcolor"><?php
if(!empty($results))
{   
    echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1'>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>S. No.</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Designation</th>";
    echo "<th>Department</th>";
    echo "<th>Tele/Mob.No.</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($results as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $n +=1 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Salutation'].' '.$row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Designation'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Tele/Mob.No.'] . "</td>";               
    echo "</tr>";
 }
  echo "</tbody>";
  echo "</table>"; 
}else
{
  echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1'><tr><td>No Records    Found</td></tr></table>";
}?></div><?php
}}

else {

       $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM teacher_directory', ARRAY_A  );
       if(!empty($results)){
       ?><div class="contcolor"><?php
        echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1'>";
       echo "<tbody>";
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<th>S. No.</th>";
       echo "<th>Name</th>";
       echo "<th>Designation</th>";
       echo "<th>Department</th>";
       echo "<th>Tele/Mob.No.</th>";
       echo "</tr>";
       foreach($results as $row){
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['S. No.'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Salutation'].' '.$row['Name'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Designation'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Department'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['Tele/Mob.No.'] . "</td>";               
       echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</tbody>";
 echo "</table>"; 
 ?></div><?php
}}
?></div></div></div></div><?php
get_footer();?></div>
```

Comment: `?page_id=911?letter=` needs to be **&** after the first ? like `?page_id=911&letter=`

Comment: I tried it But list got empty. May be I did some mistake in line count function thats why, I guess. Can you please check that also.

Comment: Can you print the variable right after it is assigned to $char ? if(isset($_GET['letter'])){ $char=$_GET['letter']; echo $char; die();

Comment: @Tismon Varghese It is Returning letter.

Comment: @Tismon Varghese  Ok  its returning(printing) the letter which I did click on it

Comment: man, use a `for` loop before anything. Don't repeat yourself

Comment: ok But what should I put in the `for` loop and where it should be place.

Comment: What are the permalink you are using .. ID or post name ?

Comment: @Prakash Rao Its the url of page in my wordpress project.

Comment: @Prakash Rao There is not issue in permalinks. Its all working fine. But the issue must be in my query or line count between funtion `if($char)`.

Comment: try to print the select query inside if($char){ echo "SELECT * FROM teacher_directory where Name LIKE     '$char%'" ; }

Comment: @Prakash Rao I tried, it didnt print anything...

Comment: This means you are not getting inside the if($char) condition....are you sure you are inside the if(isset($_GET['letter'])) try echo something inside this..

Comment: @Prakash I tried to print `echo $char;` in side `if($char)` and it did print $char value. May be problem is something else.

Comment: Try printing echo "SELECT * FROM teacher_directory where Name LIKE '$char%'" ; .. it should be printed as it is a string now not a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just change your IF condition

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM teacher_directory where Name LIKE '$char%'", ARRAY_A  );
if(!empty($sql)) { 
   /* your search result same code that you have print */ 
} else {
  /* same it is */
}
```